# Path confusion: Jupyter works, Spyder doesn't

Tags: python, windows-7, jupyter, spyder

Have an Anaconda installation on Windows 7.

I installed a bloomberg python api at `c:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\blpapi`  That's the location defaulted by the executable install wizard.

I also installed a module that wraps/abstracts the bloomberg python api (blpapi).  It's stored at `c:\Users\mds\Dropbox\_python\wedge\tia-master\tia`

I have `ipython notebook` running (jupyter).  And I have an instance of the Spyder IDE running.

In the jupyter notebook everything is working fine.  I start off with `from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal` and then write my notebook and everything works.

But when I try the same inside Jupyter, it fails, with the stacktrace complaining it cannot find the `blpapi` module.

```
  File "C:/Users/mds/Dropbox/_python/wedge/3MA_v1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

  File "C:\Users\mds\Dropbox\_python\wedge\tia-master\tia\bbg\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tia.bbg.v3api import *

  File "C:\Users\mds\Dropbox\_python\wedge\tia-master\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import blpapi
```

When the v3api.py module tries to import blpapi, it cannot find it.

Why is the jupyter notebook able to find it, but spyder cannot?  It's like I have some sort of PATH issue.  Does anyone have any debugging advice on how to check the relevant paths and setups being used on Jupyter and SpyderIDE?   Or have any other suggestion why this is failing?

Thanks

================================

**jupyter**

```
 ['', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pastebin-1.1.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master\\tia\\bbg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master\\tia', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\queuelib-1.2.2-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-21.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\.ipython']
```

**SPYDER**

```
print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pastebin-1.1.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master\\tia\\bbg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master\\tia', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Dropbox\\_python\\wedge\\tia-master', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\queuelib-1.2.2-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\users\\mds\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-21.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\mds\\.ipython']
```

Comment: The command `import sys; print(sys.path)` will print the search path for modules in both the Jupyter notebook and Spyder. What is the result?

Comment: @JitseNiesen hi.  I have put in the body of my question the results of sys.path for the ide and the notebook.   I rebooted my computer after changing the locale back from Japanese (I was having japanese unicode problems in earlier project and switching locale temp solved them). Once I rebooted, both Spyder and Jupyter worked fine. So dunno what issue this was, or why these actions might have fixed it.